# simple html dom parser $html is empty

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

When trying to parse html using *simple html parser*, I get no response. Here is the code:

```
$html = new simple_html_dom();  
$html->file_get_html('http://thepiratebay.se/search/1080p/0/7/207');
```

`$html` returns nothing. However, when I'm doing the same thing using this url, `http://thepiratebay.se/browse/207/0/7`, I get a normal response.

I don't really understand why since the url works perfectly.

A `var_dump` on `$html` returns a `bool (false)`.

I have php 5.3.1 and `allow_url_fopen` is on in **php.ini**

Comment: I'm sorry, but I did genuinely laugh at this question... Do you get any errors of any sort?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`cURL`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) and set a user-agent. Apparently thepriatebay.se does not to respond to requests without a user-agent.

This grabs the user-agent of your browser and sends it to the target.

```php
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
```

To request a web page through cURL, use the following:

```php
// Start a cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();
// Set options for the cURL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://thepiratebay.se/search/1080p/0/7/207'); // target
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']); // provide a user-agent
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // follow any redirects
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // return the result
// Execute the cURL fetch
$result = curl_exec($ch);
// Close the resource
curl_close($ch);
// Output the results
echo $result;
```